# SQL query to get all values a enum can have

Tags: postgresql, enums

Postgresql got enum support some time ago.

```
CREATE TYPE myenum AS ENUM (
'value1',
'value2',
);
```

How do I get all values specified in the enum with a query?

Comment: I have also found the following answer very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540681/list-postgres-enum-type

Answer (score 417, accepted):

If you want an array:

```
SELECT enum_range(NULL::myenum)
```

If you want a separate record for each item in the enum:

```
SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::myenum))
```

---

#### Additional Information

This solution works as expected even if your enum is not in the default schema. For example, replace `myenum` with `myschema.myenum`.

The data type of the returned records in the above query will be `myenum`. Depending on what you are doing, you may need to cast to text. e.g.

```
SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::myenum))::text
```

If you want to specify the column name, you can append `AS my_col_name`.

---

Credit to Justin Ohms for pointing out some additional tips, which I incorporated into my answer.

Comment: This answer is much more concise.  Nice contribution!

Comment: The unnest call will return records of type myenum with a column name of "myenum".   You might also want to cast the enum to text and specify a column name by adding something like.   ::text AS my_column

Comment: To understand more about enum functions you can view this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-enum.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html

Comment: what is the meaning of `NULL::`?

Comment: ::myenum is a type cast to myenum. 'value1'::myenum is casting a string to enum. NULL::myenum is casting NULL to myenum.

Comment: @ChrisL thanks. it seems very strange. why can't we do `SELECT enum_range(myenum)`? What is the meaning of casting `null`?

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner. I type exactly ```SELECT enum_range(NULL::myenum)``` and i received 'type "myenum" does not exist'. Am i supposed to replace certain words with my actual table "Role" or the enum column "type"?

Comment: @Sydney You would replace myenum with the enum column type.

Comment: How can I use enum in a WHERE clause ?

e.g: 

select *
from public."table"
where public."table"."enumtypecolumn" = "Enum value"

Answer (score 43):

Try:

```
SELECT e.enumlabel
  FROM pg_enum e
  JOIN pg_type t ON e.enumtypid = t.oid
  WHERE t.typname = 'myenum'
```

Comment: If you have the same enum in more than one schema, this might need to be narrowed down a bit.  If that's the case, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html for details.

Comment: I think you need to prefix 'myenum' with an underscore.  Check out my answer if you need to get enum values and the enum name may be used in more than one schema.

Comment: If enumeration order is important, append `ORDER BY e.enumsortorder` to the query. The enumerated values will most likely be out of order if new values were inserted into the enumeration type using `BEFORE` or `AFTER`.

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::your_enum))::text AS your_column
```

This will return a single column result set of the contents of the enum "your_enum" with a column named "your_column" of type text.

Comment: Casting to text allows you to sort the values

Answer (score 8):

In case someone is looking for the `psql` way then it's

`\dT+ <your enum>`

Comment: It starts with backslash, actually.

Answer (score 4):

You can get all the enum values for an enum using the following query.  The query lets you pick which namespace the enum lives in too (which is required if the enum is defined in multiple namespaces; otherwise you can omit that part of the query).

```
SELECT enumlabel
FROM pg_enum
WHERE enumtypid=(SELECT typelem
                 FROM pg_type
                 WHERE typname='_myenum' AND
                 typnamespace=(SELECT oid
                               FROM pg_namespace
                               WHERE nspname='myschema'))
```

Comment: What do you mean that it is the array type?  This works for me (PostgreSQL 9.0).

Comment: +1 This worked for me whereas @Kev's answer did not, due to the use of schemas in my DB.