# How do i query values of an enum in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, enums

Hi i want to use an enum in postgresql as an alternative to making a table, because the values my never change, but i want to be able to retrieve these values for an application that might check just in case they do, is there any way the query it to get the values?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616123/sql-query-to-get-all-values-a-enum-can-have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the manual: Functions and Operators / Enum Support Functions
You probably want the enum_range(...) function.
Alternatively, you could look in the system catalogues: pg_enum

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::your_enum))::text AS your_column
```

This will return a single column result set of the contents of the enum "your_enum" with a column named "your_column" of type text.