# list Postgres ENUM type

Tags: postgresql

The [suggested query to list ENUM types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660787/how-to-list-custom-types-using-postgres-information-schema) is great. But, it merely lists of the `schema` and the `typname`.  How do I list out the actual ENUM values? For example, in the linked answer above, I would want the following result

```
schema         type      values
-------------  --------  -------
communication  channels  'text_message','email','phone_call','broadcast'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query to get all values a enum can have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616123/sql-query-to-get-all-values-a-enum-can-have)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

```
select n.nspname as enum_schema,  
       t.typname as enum_name,  
       e.enumlabel as enum_value
from pg_type t 
   join pg_enum e on t.oid = e.enumtypid  
   join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace;
```

Comment: sweet... even better to use `string_agg(e.enumlabel, ', ') as enum_value` with the appropriate `GROUP BYs`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 223):

You can list the data type via

```
\dT+ channels
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS

Comment: @AlisonR. I believe the author was looking for an sql syntax. the solution in this answer is only good for the native postgres cli client.

Answer (score 170):

```sql
select enum_range(null::my_enum);
```

where `my_enum` is the enum type name.

Documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-enum.html

Comment: Use `select unnest(enum_range(null, null::name_of_enum_type));` to get one value per row.

Answer (score 39):

This: `SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::myenum))` returns enum types as rows.

Answer (score 22):

I always forget how to do this.  As per the other answer and the comment, here it is a comma-separated list.  I like copy-paste snippets.  Thanks for the help:

```
select n.nspname as enum_schema,  
    t.typname as enum_name,
    string_agg(e.enumlabel, ', ') as enum_value
from pg_type t 
    join pg_enum e on t.oid = e.enumtypid  
    join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
group by enum_schema, enum_name;
```

Answer (score 7):

SELECT enum_range(NULL::myenum)

Comment: Totally love this, shortest version ever. If you need to verify your data before casting it, you can run a row=any(SELECT enum_range(NULL::myenum)) either in the query or in WHERE clause and you'll see where you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

@dpb:

If you want to create a permanent easy access method for this, you could always create a view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW oublic.enumz AS 
 SELECT n.nspname AS enum_schema,
  t.typname AS enum_name,
  e.enumlabel AS enum_value
 FROM pg_type t
 JOIN pg_enum e ON t.oid = e.enumtypid
 JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace;
```

You could then create a trigger for the insert command.

The above will store this in the database for future reference purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This lists all enum-typed **columns** and their potential values:

```
SELECT
  table_schema || '.' || table_name || '.' || column_name as field_name,
  pg_enum.enumlabel as value
FROM pg_type
  JOIN pg_enum ON pg_enum.enumtypid = pg_type.oid
  JOIN pg_namespace on pg_type.typnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
  JOIN information_schema.columns ON (information_schema.columns.udt_name = pg_type.typname AND information_schema.columns.udt_schema = pg_namespace.nspname)
WHERE pg_type.typtype = 'e'
ORDER BY field_name, pg_enum.enumsortorder;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add order

```sql
SELECT
  n.nspname AS enum_schema,
  t.typname AS enum_name,
  e.enumlabel AS enum_value
FROM
  pg_type t
  JOIN pg_enum e ON t.oid = e.enumtypid
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
ORDER BY
  enum_name,
  e.enumsortorder;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have the table and column name, (but not the type name) use this:

```
SELECT pg_enum.enumlabel
FROM pg_type
 JOIN pg_enum ON pg_enum.enumtypid = pg_type.oid
 JOIN information_schema.columns ON information_schema.columns.udt_name =
                                    pg_type.typname
WHERE pg_type.typtype = 'e' AND
      table_name = $1 AND column_name = $2 ORDER BY pg_enum.enumsortorder
```

If you use `enum_range` on a column (in contrast to the other answers which used it on a type) it will return data for each row that exists, which is not what you want. So use the above query instead.

Comment: Since you don't join `pg_namespace`, this results in wrong associations if the same enum name is present in more than one schema...