# select Postgres enumeration only if it exists

Tags: postgresql

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624919/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-define-type-already-exists-in-postgresql) tells how to check if a type exists in Postgres. I tried to use it like this:

```
select
case when exists (select 1 from pg_type where typname = 'my_type')
then unnest(enum_range(NULL::my_type))
else null
end
```

unfortunately, Postgres is not lazy so this gives me a type error when the type does not exist. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9540681/330315

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to enumerate values of a type, you can get from `pg_enum` without type cast :

```
 SELECT
   T.typname,
   E.enumlabel,
   E.enumsortorder
 FROM
   pg_enum E
   INNER JOIN pg_type T ON (E.enumtypid = T.oid)
 WHERE
   T.typname = 'my_type'
 ;
```