# PostgreSQL - Right Index choice for a status field (varchar)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with lots of entries and a varchar field with length 8 that represents different statuses. There are only about 5 different statuses, lets say 'STATUS1', 'STATUS2', ... and most of the time it is NULL.

When I index the field, it doesn't do much because there are a lot of equal values and then postgres doesn't use the index.

My question is: Is there a way to index such a field and make it faster? Most of the time I query over `status IS NULL` and I think I can't make that faster. But what if I check for `status = 'STATUS1'`?

Comment: If performance is a concern to you, I think you should consider using integers instead of varchars here. If the status names are important, you can always create a satellite relation containing the association from the integers to the status names.

Comment: It all depends on how many rows `where status is null` would remove from the result. If only a few rows are returned by that condition, then Postgres **will** use an index on the status column. If that is the majority of all rows an index won't really help (but creating a partial index is worth trying)

Comment: I had that in mind too, but I would rather keep the Varchar field. Performance is not crucial at this point, I just wanted to know if there is a common way that I miss completely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) in some cases. Let's say you have lots of queries similar to

```
SELECT *
  FROM the_table
 WHERE color in ('green', 'blue') AND status = 'STATUS1' ;
```

This query would most probably run (much) faster if you create a `partial index`:

```
CREATE TABLE the_table
(
   color text, 
   status character varying(8)
    /* and anything you need */
) ; 

CREATE INDEX
  ON public.the_table (color)
  WHERE status = 'STATUS1' ;
```

If using PostgreSQL (o any other database which allows it), I'd probably be creating an [`enumerated type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-enum.html) as well, instead of varchar. You have two advantages: only the enumerated values will be allowed (so "autochecking"), and the space needed to store the info (and index it) is less than varchar(8):

```
CREATE TYPE status_type AS ENUM
   ('STATUS1',
    'STATUS2',
    'STATUS3');
```

and then create the table with it:

```
CREATE TABLE the_table
(
   color text, 
   status status_type
    /* and anything you need */
) ;
```

If you need to know (programmatically) which are the allowed values for the enumeration (for instance, to create a menu), [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540681/list-postgres-enum-type).

If the database wouldn't allow for enums, I'd normalize to a small[ish] table of (anonymous_id_PK, status_value) pairs.

Comment: I guess that is the best solution for this then. I will consider the Enums as well. Thank you!